ASP.NET Core Web API : CORS error while try to authorize user from Azure AD
I am trying setup an application which is an open source built on .NET Core, below is the path for the application source code from where I have downloaded it.
https://gitlab.com/sis-cc/.stat-suite/dotstatsuite-core-auth-management
I am able to run the application successfully and hit the endpoints when I disable the authentication in appsettings.json file, I am now trying to enable to the authentication and for that I made changes to the appsettings.json file, I changed the db connection, authority value, authorization url, scope value etc.
{
    "DotStatSuiteCoreCommonDbConnectionString": "Data Source=dbserver;Initial Catalog=DotStat.Common;User ID=USERNAME;Password=XXXXXX",
    "AutoLog2Google": false,
    "GoogleLogLevel": "Debug",
    "GoogleProjectId": "XXXX",
    "GoogleLogId": "AUTH_SERVICE",
    "auth": {
        "enabled":true,
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/cdk.org/",
        "clientId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
        //"requireHttps": true,
        "validateIssuer": true,
        "claimsMapping": {
            "email": "email",
            "groups": "groups"
        },
        "authorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/21adghhrr-345sdg-4534645dfgfdgh/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        "tokenUrl": "",
        "scopes": [ "user.read" ]
    }
}

I have deployed the app to the Azure app, now when I am trying to access the Swagger URL, the Swagger page loads, and on the home page when I click on the authorize tab and select the scope "user.read" checkbox and click on authorize tab, I get this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/21adghhrr-345sdg-4534645dfgfdgh/oauth2/v2.0/authorize' from origin 'https://dotstatauthservicedev.ites.cdk.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

My understanding is that here from Swagger when we click on the Authorize button a request will be made to the AuthorizationUrl which Azure active directory to authenticate the user and is response I should get a token which can be used for calling the API endpoints.
Any suggestions on how to get this resolved?
Update : Based on the responses and feedback i got here on stackoverflow i made changes to appsettings, i changed TokenUrl value from "" to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/21adghhrr-345sdg-4534645dfgfdgh/oauth2/v2.0/token" ,after making this change i tried clicking the Authorize button on the swagger home page and this time i got anothe error as below.

Bad Request, error: invalid request, desciption: AADSTS9002326:
Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page
Application' client-type. Request origin:
'https://dotstatauthservicedev.ites.cdk.org'

After this i changed the Apptype from the app registration in azure from webapp tp SPA, after this change which i tried clicking the Authorize button on the swagger i got Authorized message succesfully, now with the Token i received when i tried to execute the Endpoint of my API i got a different error

Error: Response status is 401, Bearer error="invalid_token", error
description="The signature is invalid"

I am thinking that the Token i got from Azure AD and the application is trying to compare the token signature and it is not matching, any inputs on how to get this resolved ?

Can you please share the configuration steps that you followed in order to create the app registration? Have you set the correct platform under the Platform Configurations of the app registration?

Anyway it's a CROS error right now, and I noticed that you have builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost", "http://127.0.0.1") in your codes. Could you pls try to use allow all origins for test purpose and see whether it's solved or not?

@TinyWang I removed the line builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost", "http://127.0.0.1") and replaced it with builder.AllowAnyOrigin.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod(); still i see the same issue... May be this is because in my case my API is trying to make a call to Azure AD and for that request i am getting the CORS error

Thanks for your confirmation @Sayan and could you pls try my codes below and see whether it worked for you? We can test locally at first. By the way, does the issue occurred when you tried to click the "lock" icon and do the authentication action?

@TinyWang Yes. when i click the Authorize button with a lock icon on the swagger home page..

Your code doesn't work in my side anyway and pls allow me to share my working sample. I have an asp.net core web api application integrating Azure AD to protect my API. Here's my Program.cs. Comparing with your codes, I test to use AuthorizationCode as the Flow but it didn't work for me. In the meantime, the TokenUrl might have something wrong within your code. You didn't define value in appsetting for  "tokenUrl": "", so that this line TokenUrl = new Uri(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_auth.TokenUrl) ? _auth.AuthorizationUrl.Replace("openid-connect/auth", "openid-connect/token") : _auth.TokenUrl), shouldn't work for you, as the AuthorizationUrl doesn't have openid-connect in it.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {
                        "api://clientId/Tiny.Read", "API permission description"
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List < string > ()
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
     options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
     options.OAuthClientId("{client_id}");
     options.OAuthClientSecret("{client_secret}");
     options.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

my test result.


Here's the blog I followed to configure my API: https://www.josephguadagno.net/2022/06/03/enabling-user-authentication-in-swagger-using-microsoft-identity

Thank you for sparing your time to look into this, the TokenURL that is getting assigned using the above code you highlighted is https://login.microsoftonline.com/21adghhrr-345sdg-4534645dfgfdgh/oauth2/v2.0/authorize , do you think this is incorrect ?

token url shall be https://login.microsoftonline.com/21adghhrr-345sdg-4534645dfgfdgh/oauth2/v2.0/token   @Sayan

I made updates to my post above, do you have inputs for the same

The operations we are trying to do are on the web api application which is not SPA so that the error message doesn't mean we should change the  platform in Azure AD. In the meantime, how about trying my configuration？My codes for builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen
